# Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies but IT IS

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console

I added paypal donation button in my android app.
When i tried to release the app bundle in the closed test section, my app was rejected because i violate the payments policy.

- So i decided to remove the paypal button and i make a new app bundle with a new version code. The app was rejected again for the **same** problem.
- So i decided to remove the entire page, but the app was rejected again for the **same** problem.

I downloaded and tried to install the apk from the rejected bundle on my smartphone and the paypal page isn't there. In the report email, the error is always the **same**: the donation button.
Now, how they can find the donation button if i **removed** it???

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Make sure you have updated every single track with the offending code removed (from internal release to production) - Google's review process is not good and you are just their latest victim.